# How to create multiple markers in GoogleMaps with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to add multiple markers in my MapView. How to add multiple markers in same mapview using swiftui?

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()

    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        marker.title = "XYZ"
        marker.snippet = "ABCD"
        marker.map = mapView
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my sample,

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let cities = [
        [
            "name": "Yangon",
            "lat": 16.8409,
            "long": 96.1735
        ],
        [
            "name": "Mandalay",
            "lat": 21.9588,
            "long": 96.0891
        ]
    ]

    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {
        for city in cities {
            let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: city["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: city["long"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
            marker.title = city["name"] as? String
            marker.snippet = "Welcome to \(city["name"] as! String)"
            marker.map = mapView
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. which latitude and longitude should I mention in camera  `GMSCameraPosition.camera`?

Comment: This is what you gotta think on your own

Comment: Thank You, Now I understood. Given a common location in "GMSCameraPosition.camera", now its working